# Bump Maps and how to get more details in them

Tags: texturing, materials, modifiers

I've been trying to give this particular artwork an embossed look with details, but I'm falling short. This is what I have:

[image]

I have been placing the image on a plane as a bump map, but not getting the desired effect.

The image in green is what I'm looking for:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please add what you want your result to look like. Reference images are necessary for something like this.

Comment: The image in green is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a software like [CrazyBump](http://www.crazybump.com/), [Knald](https://www.knaldtech.com/), or [SmartNormal](http://www.smart-page.net/smartnormal/) to create a normal map based on the image you have and add that to your material.

If you are using cycles you can run the normal map through a *normal map* node and plug that into your shaders.

[image]

Here's the result I got with SmartNormal.  You could improve a lot by spending more time tweaking the settings, but it's a start.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Blender Compositor for your final image.

Image before compositing some contrast.

[image]

Image after compositing with more contrast.

[image]

Compositing Nodes with Black, Middle, and White Thresholds Color Ramp

[image]

Comment: eeewww... good answer but i really don't like the arrows.